# How do you place child in front of a parents sibling with higher z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

How do you place child in front of a parents sibling with higher z-index?

I want the pink box to apear in front of the green.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tim86/YRTxt/

[image: example]

```
<style>
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
}
#red, #green{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
#red{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
#pink{
    background-color:pink;
    height:250px;
    width:150px;
    top:50px;
    right:20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:40;
}
#green{
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
    top:-50px;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="red">
        <div id="pink">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="green">

    </div>
</div>
​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `position:relative;` from `#red` and it's done.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbilal/YRTxt/5/)

Comment: Thanks, that's great! A short explanation would be awesome.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, but I can't remove the relative positioning from the element. What are other options?